# Email verification in React native Social Media App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, firebase-authentication

I have a react-native social media app. It lets user sign up and create password. It stores the user authenticated email in firebase database.

My question is, how can I make user verify if the are not using someone else's email.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know if you are using Cloud Firestore ou Realtime Database but you can set rules for this checking email before write into db [see more info here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started)

see also [firebase auth](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to send a verification email to the user, and then check the `emailVerified` property in their user profile.

To send the email from the JavaScript SDK, see [Send a user a verification emailSend a user a verification email](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#send_a_user_a_verification_email) in the documentation. If you're using `react-native-firebase`, the method can be found [here](https://rnfirebase.io/reference/auth/user#sendEmailVerification).